# Message dont appears immediatly in the chat activity!!! What i have to do?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

**Code:**

```
public class Chat extends ListActivity {
protected EditText mMessageChat;
protected Button mSendMessageBtn;
protected List<ParseObject> mMessage;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    if (currentUser != null) {
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Status");
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> status, ParseException e) {
                mMessage = status;
                MessageAdapter adapter = new MessageAdapter(getListView().getContext(), mMessage);
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
    }

    mMessageChat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.chatMessageText);
    mSendMessageBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SendMessageBtn);
    mSendMessageBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
            String currentUserUsername = currentUser.getUsername();
            String newStatus = mMessageChat.getText().toString();
            if (newStatus.isEmpty()) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Chat.this);
                builder.setMessage("Please type in a Message!");
                builder.setTitle("Oops!");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            }
            ParseObject statusObject = new ParseObject("Status");
            statusObject.put("newStatus", newStatus);
            statusObject.put("user", currentUserUsername);
            statusObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(Chat.this, "Send!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Chat.this);
                        builder.setMessage(e.getMessage());
                        builder.setTitle("Sorry!");
                        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                dialogInterface.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                        dialog.show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_chat, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

What I have to do to see the message immediately in the chat window? I send a message but the message doesn't appears immediately in the chat. I have to go back in the app menu and then go back to the chat and then I can see the message I have sent. I'm using parse as the backend. I am searching for days for the solution. Can somebody help me?

Comment: As you're using Parse, you need to explicitly fetch the new messages, they won't be distributed to the device automatically. So just use a timer to check for new messages?

Comment: Is it possible with a handler? And when, must i create a new class for the handler? Where can i wrote it to my code, has somebody an example? Sorry for my bad English but i try my best... I am new to android so please forgive me...!

Comment: Hello, somebody out there????